# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS] error when trying to install/run android app on phone (not emulator)

Tags: android, android-studio, installation

I'm getting a install failed error due to no matching ABIS when I try to run my app on my phone from android studio but I'm not sure how this can be the case since I'm using a phone and not an emulator. I have uninstalled the existing app, restarted the phone, restarted my computer, and updated android studio and gradle to no luck. I'm not sure what could cause this since it's (to my understanding) due to problems with emulated architectures. It should be noted that the error only started recently and without any noticeable changes in my version history. I'm on an htc one m8(which uses a snapdragon 801 processor with an arm v7 rev. 1 architecture) running android 6.0 and My app level gradle build is as follows:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "REDACTED"
        minSdkVersion getMinSdk()
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 131
        versionName "1.2.58"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        renderscriptTargetApi 18
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile rootProject.file("keys/debug.keystore")
            v2SigningEnabled false
        }
        release {
           REDACTED
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "CRASHLYTICS", "true"
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            ext.betaDistributionGroupAliases = "testers"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "CRASHLYTICS", "false"
            ext.betaDistributionGroupAliases = "testers"
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
        staging.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
        staging {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "CRASHLYTICS", "true"
            ext.betaDistributionGroupAliases = "testers"
            applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            svg.srcDir 'src/main/svg'
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'x86'
            universalApk true
        }
    }
}

victor {
    // Do not generate these densities for SVG assets
    excludeDensities = ['ldpi']
}

def getMinSdk() {
    for (String taskName : project.getGradle().startParameter.taskNames) {
        if (taskName.toLowerCase().contains("debug")) {
            return 21
        }
    }

    return 15
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
    compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:1.+'
    compile 'com.trello:rxlifecycle:0.6.1'

    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:1.3.0@aar'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.2@aar') { transitive = true; }

    compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.1') { exclude module: 'support-v4' }
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:1.6.6@aar') { transitive = true; }
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:1.0.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile 'com.appyvet:materialrangebar:1.0'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:3.1.0'

    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'

    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.8'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxrelay:rxrelay:1.0.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'

    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.5'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.5'
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'

    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
//    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta2'
    stagingCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'

}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    // assign different version code for each output
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // Filter is null for universal APKs.
        def filter = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)

        if (!android.splits.abi.universalApk) {
            // change the version codes
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    project.ext.versionCodes.get(filter) * 1000000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
        }

        if (filter == null) {
            tasks.findAll {
                it.name.startsWith(
                        "crashlyticsUploadDistribution${variant.name.capitalize()}")
            }.each {
                it.doFirst {
                    ext.betaDistributionApkFilePath = output.outputFile.absolutePath
                }
            }
        }
        if (filter == null) {
            tasks.findAll {
                it.name.startsWith(
                        "crashlyticsUploadSymbols${variant.name.capitalize()}")
            }.each {
                it.doFirst {
                    ext.betaDistributionApkFilePath = output.outputFile.absolutePath
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: okay we need to know which cpu your phone uses so that we can make sure in your gradle file that its assembling the right abi for your phone..if you have the phone open there is an about option in the settings app and the cpu its using should be in that about screen..its probably another armeabi but not the armeabi-v7a one

Comment: Probably your phone has a different processor architecture like `x86_64` or `arm64-v8a` or some other not listed in your splits. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html

Comment: @FredGrott The htc one m8 uses a snapdragon 801 cpu which has an arm v7 revision 1 architecture

Comment: @VictorK it has an arm v7 revision 1 architecture

Comment: ah than its amrv7 not amrv7a I think, that might be why you get the error of missing armeabi..so it might be as simple as adding that to your gradle script file

Comment: bTW the armeabi refers to the instruction set used

Comment: @FredGrott added that to the script with no luck. same result.

Comment: @FredGrott Looking closer at the log file for the failure, it appears that when launching the app it executes "adb push C:\..\app-x86-debug.apk" which is obviously the wrong abi. Any idea what might cause this?